# how to put boxes around some variables in a table?

Tags: tables, tabularx

So I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
        
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &\multicolumn{5}{c}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
        \headerrow & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Samples}} 
        
        
         & 0 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\) &  \(8.67*e^{-17} \)&  \(4.13*e^{-24}\) &  \(1.16*e^{-17}\) &  \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\ 
        
        & 1 & \(1.16*e^{-16}\) &  \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &  \(9.14*e^{-25}\) &  \(3.63*e^{-22}\) &  \(2.69*e^{-11}\) \\
        
        & 2 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) &  \(7.85*e^{-34}\) &  \(9.93*e^{-01}\) &  \(3.74*e^{-04}\) &  \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\
        
        & 3 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\)&   \(5.13*e^{-31}\)&   \(5.02*e^{-04}\)    & \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &    \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\
        
        & 4 & \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)& \(2.52*e^{-25}\)&   \(4.64*e^{-20}\)&   \(9.99*e^{-01}\)
         
        \end{tabular}
        
        \label{tbl:predan}
        \end{table}
        
   
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

So I want to put some boxes around some variables in tables. It would be good when the color can be chosen too. something like the next Foto.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `\headerrow` command?

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489942/   can help you.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, its the header of the table

Comment: @Zarko yeah, it helped. thx

Comment: So it's only the text ‘header row’?

Comment: @Bernard yes, it is only the header row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.13 of 2021/03/23), you have a command `\Block` with keys `draw` and `borders` to draw borders of a cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}
& \Block{1-5}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
& & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\Block{5-1}{\rotate Samples} 
& 0 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\) &  \(8.67*e^{-17} \)&  \(4.13*e^{-24}\) &  \(1.16*e^{-17}\) &  \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\ 
& 1 & 
      \Block[borders={top,bottom,left}]{}{\(1.16*e^{-16}\)} 
                      &  \Block[draw=red]{}{\(9.99*e^{-01}\)} 
                                          &  
                                             \Block[borders={top,bottom,right}]{}{\(9.14*e^{-25}\)} 
                                                             &  \(3.63*e^{-22}\) &  \(2.69*e^{-11}\) \\
& 2 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) &  \(7.85*e^{-34}\) &  \(9.93*e^{-01}\) &  \(3.74*e^{-04}\) &  \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\
& 3 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\) &   \(5.13*e^{-31}\)&   \(5.02*e^{-04}\)&  \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &  \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\
& 4 & \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)  & \(2.52*e^{-25}\)  &  \(4.64*e^{-20}\) &  \(9.99*e^{-01}\)
\end{NiceTabular}
   
\end{document}
```

If you prefer to have the instructions of formatting after the array, it's possible. In the environments of `nicematrix` you can, in the `\CodeAfter`, use Tikz to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}


\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}
& \Block{1-5}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
& & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\Block{5-1}{\rotate Samples} 
& 0 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\)  & \(8.67*e^{-17} \) &  \(4.13*e^{-24}\) &  \(1.16*e^{-17}\) &  \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\ 
& 1 & \(1.16*e^{-16}\) & \(9.99*e^{-01}\) & \(9.14*e^{-25}\) &  \(3.63*e^{-22}\) &  \(2.69*e^{-11}\) \\
& 2 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) &  \(7.85*e^{-34}\) &  \(9.93*e^{-01}\) &  \(3.74*e^{-04}\) &  \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\
& 3 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\) &   \(5.13*e^{-31}\)&   \(5.02*e^{-04}\)&  \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &  \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\
& 4 & \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)  & \(2.52*e^{-25}\)  &  \(4.64*e^{-20}\) &  \(9.99*e^{-01}\)
\CodeAfter
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (4-|4) -- (4-|3) -- (5-|3) -- (5-|4) ;
 \draw (4-|5) -- (4-|6) -- (5-|6) -- (5-|5) ;
 \draw [red] (4-|4) rectangle (5-|5) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
   
\end{document}
```

With both syntax, the ouput is as follows.

[image: Output of the above code]

You need several commpilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

Answer (score 5):

I propose this code, with basic packages:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, multirow, bigstrut, float}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.8pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &\multicolumn{5}{c}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
    headerrow & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Samples}}

     & 0 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\) & \(8.67*e^{-17} \)& \(4.13*e^{-24}\) & \(1.16*e^{-17}\) & \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\
    \hhline{~~- >{\arrayrulecolor{red}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}
    & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\(1.16*e^{-16}\) \bigstrut[t]}&\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red}\vrule width 0.8pt}c!{\color{red}\vrule width 0.8pt}}{ \(9.99*e^{-01}\) }& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\(9.14*e^{-25}\)} & \(3.63*e^{-22}\) & \(2.69*e^{-11}\) \\
    \hhline{~~- >{\arrayrulecolor{red}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}
    & 2 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) & \(7.85*e^{-34}\) & \(9.93*e^{-01}\) & \(3.74*e^{-04}\) & \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\

    & 3 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\)& \(5.13*e^{-31}\)& \(5.02*e^{-04}\) & \(9.99*e^{-01}\) & \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\

    & 4 & \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)& \(2.52*e^{-25}\)& \(4.64*e^{-20}\)& \(9.99*e^{-01}\)

    \end{tabular}

    \label{tbl:predan}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested in the answer, I used tikzmark to draw the boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}   
\usepackage{booktabs,cellspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &\multicolumn{5}{c}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
        \headerrow & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Samples}} 
        
         & 0 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\) &  \(8.67*e^{-17} \)&  \(4.13*e^{-24}\) &  \(1.16*e^{-17}\) &  \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\ 
        
        & 1 & \tikzmarknode{a}{\(1.16*e^{-16}\)} & \tikzmarknode{c}{\(9.99*e^{-01}\)} &  \tikzmarknode{b}{\(9.14*e^{-25}\)} &  \(3.63*e^{-22}\) & \(2.69*e^{-11}\)  \\
        
        & 2 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) &  \(7.85*e^{-34}\) &  \(9.93*e^{-01}\) &  \(3.74*e^{-04}\) &  \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\
        
        & 3 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\)&   \(5.13*e^{-31}\)&   \(5.02*e^{-04}\)    & \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &    \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\
        
        & 4 & \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)& \(2.52*e^{-25}\)&   \(4.64*e^{-20}\)&   \(9.99*e^{-01}\)
         
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tbl:predan}
\end{table}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[draw=red, thin, inner sep=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b)] {};
\node[draw=green, thin, inner sep=1.5pt,rounded corners, fit=(c) (c)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]